# Graphing $f(x,y) = x / (x^2 + y^2)$ in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have been having trouble plotting the following in MatLab:

$$f(x,y) = \frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}$$

I seem to have no trouble plotting similar functions (using a meshgrid). In fact, if I just try plotting $z = x^2 + y^2$, I don't run into any issues. Why is that that when I try to put an x in the numerator that things fall apart? I have also tried plotting with GeoGebra, but have had no luck.

Is there a way to plot this in MatLab? I am learning how to calculate tangent planes, and I would like to see visual representations of my work to confirm that I am arriving at correct conclusions.

Comment: The function is not defined at $x=y=0$.

Comment: Does that mean I can not plot it in MatLab?

Comment: Don't include $(0,0)$ in your plotting range. It is not clear what 'falling apart' means here...

Comment: How can I define a range from -10 to 10 excluding zero? I have been using meshgrid like so: [X,Y] = meshgrid(-10:.1:10);

Comment: Try the following commands:
1. x = -20:1:20; y = -20:1:20;
2. [X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
3. mesh(X./(X.^2+Y.^2))

Comment: And by the way geogebra works good using f(x,y)=x/(x^2+y^2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the following commands we will get the required plot:

1. Initializing - $x = -20:1:20; \ y = -20:1:20$.
2. Creating grid - $[X,Y] \ = \ \text{meshgrid}(x,y);$
3. Ploting - $\text{mesh}(X./(X.^2+Y.^2))$

The result
[image: $\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$]

Comment: This works because the plotting ignores Nan (poor Nan).

Comment: @copper.hat, this is true, thanks for noticing. I think that this is what the OP asked for.

Comment: This is great, thanks!

Interesting point though. In MatLab, if I use plot3(1, 2, 0.2, 'marker', 'o') the little circle is not actually on the surface. However, if I plot the same point in GeoGebra, it sits on the surface.

Any idea why?